# Is there a way to change the eslint of the webpack for the create-react-app without ejecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want change the rules for the eslint for the react app without ejecting.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please edit your post and write everything you tried, and what didn't work. Make sure your question is clear enough in order to be understandable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add new ESLint rules by following just 3 simple steps.

1. Create .eslintrc.js under the src folder of the your project.
2. Add the following lines in the file:

   module.exports = {
        "extends": "react-app",
        "rules" : {
            "indent": ["error", 4] // A custom style-related rule for example
            // More custom rules here
        }
    }

This way, we will be telling our IDE to extend the base ESLint rules provided by the create-react-app and then follow some rules defined by us.

3. In your `package.json`, add the following script:

   "lint:fix": "eslint src/**/*.js --fix",

This is mainly for CLI and CI/CD environment.

Now default setup in most of the IDEs are that they would read the configuration from src/.eslintrc.js. Hence you should now see errors/warnings from your custom eslintrc file on your IDE as well

Src - http://rahulgaba.com/front-end/2019/02/17/Use-custom-eslint-config-in-create-react-app-using-three-simple-steps-No-external-dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

Add an `.eslintrc` file to the root of your project and in that extend the `eslint-config-react-app` and add your rules/overrides, e.g.

```
// .eslintrc
{
  "extends": "react-app",
  "rules": {
    // enable additional rules or override from react-app
    "indent": ["error", 4],
```